# How to dynamically name an attribute?

Tags: xslt

I'm looking to get a custom attribute for anchor tag from xsl.

Is it possible to get the name of the attribute dynamically from xml?

Here is what I tried :

```
<xsl:attribute name="<xsl:value-of select="id"/>">
   <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why don't you post an example of the input, and the expected output ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can pass a variable as `name` value.

```
<xsl:variable name="attributeName" select="id"/>
<xsl:attribute name="{$attributeName}">
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simpify the solution from @Savard to

```
<xsl:attribute name="{id}">
    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

or if you are using XSLT 2.0, to

```
<xsl:attribute name="{id}" select="value"/>
```

Comment: <xsl:template name="gen_attr_if_positive_int">
        <xsl:param name="attr_name"/>
        <xsl:param name="attr_value"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$attr_value &gt; 0">
                <xsl:attribute name="{attr_name}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$attr_value"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
--------- gives me   XTDE0850  Invalid attribute name: ----- so does {$attr_name} or just $attr_name

Answer (score 0):

Note, you can also mix-and-match dynamic and literal parts to a name:

```
<xsl:attribute name="{name}_example">Test</xsl:attribute>
```